# Multiple store_accessors with identical keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model `Profile` with hstore field `paypal_credentials`:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  store_accessor :paypal_credentials, :preapproval_key, :preapproval_url
  ...
end
```

Now I need to add the second hstore field named `customer_paypal_credentials` with identical keys. How can I use `store_accessor` in this way? I can't find anything about prefix/suffix functionality of `store_accessor`.

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to get `paypal_credentials` hash by calling `customer_paypal_credentials`? Or if there is another field in table then `store_accessor :customer_paypal_credentials` not working?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky, no, I want to get `paypal_credentials -> preapproval_key` by calling `preapproval_key` and to get `customer_paypal_credentials -> preapproval_key` by calling, for example, `customer_preapproval_key` (if I could add prefix functionality somehow). But as I can see there is no way to do this.

Comment: Did you consider to use custom getters?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky, there are too many keys in hstore fields:)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in Rails 6 and above: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

From the doc:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :color, :homepage ], coder: JSON
  store :parent, accessors: [ :name ], coder: JSON, prefix: true
  store :spouse, accessors: [ :name ], coder: JSON, prefix: :partner
  store :settings, accessors: [ :two_factor_auth ], suffix: true
  store :settings, accessors: [ :login_retry ], suffix: :config
end
```